# Storing the value or name of the button selected on a modal popup form to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the javascript confirm to track whether the user clicked okay or cancel.
Confirm is not easy to style and I want a better look. How can I apply the function 
confirmDialog below so that I can determine if the user clicked ok or cancel and store
the result in a variable pleaseContinue.

```
        var pleaseContinue = true;
        if (firstForm.length > 0) {
         pleaseContinue = confirm("All the data that is not saved will be lost.Do you want to proceed ? ");

        }

        if pleaseContinue()
        {
            //do something
        }

        var confirmed = false;
        function confirmDialog(obj)
        {
            if(!confirmed)
            {
                $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
                    resizable: false,
                    height:140,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        "Yes": function()
                        {
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                            confirmed = true; obj.click();
                        },
                        "No": function()
                        {
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            return confirmed;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that: the confirm function is blocking and you need to handle the events if You're using an HTML-based form. Use a callback function instead:

```
function confirmDialog(onok)
{
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function()
            {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                onok();
            },
            "No": function()
            {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How will the callback function work? How will I call this function above?

Comment: Maybe the question is how do I call this confirmDialog function?

Comment: you call confirmDialog with a callback method as an argument. The callback method will be called whenever Yes is clicked.